Bounds on hitting time of sum of i.i.d. random variables
I have a sequence $(X_i)_{i\geq 1}$ of i.i.d. random variables taking values in $\mathbb Z$. I know that each $X_i$ has mean $0$ and finite variance $\sigma^2$. Let $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$. Then I can view $(S_n)_{n\geq 1}$ as a random walk on $\mathbb Z$ (with possibly large step sizes). For $B\subseteq\mathbb Z$, let $\tau_B=\inf\{n\geq 1:S_n\in B\}$. Are there any techniques that I can use to obtain upper bounds on the probability that $\tau_B$ lies in some range?
I have two specific settings where I would like to apply such bounds. The first is trying to bound the probability that the random walk veers too far away from the origin in a given amount of time. Let $K$ be a large positive integer (say $K=1000$). Since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}S_n$ should be approximately normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$, I should expect that the random walk should not veer more than $K\sigma\sqrt{m}$ from the origin during the first $m$ steps (when $m$ is large). To put this into the above setting, I can let $B=(-\infty,-K\sigma\sqrt{m}]\cup[K\sigma\sqrt{m},\infty)$. Then I want to show that $\mathbb P(\tau_B\leq m)$ is small.
For the second setting, say for concreteness that $B=[3\sigma\sqrt{m},\infty)$ (for $m$ large). I want to show that it is unlikely for $\tau_B$ to lie in some relatively narrow window. For instance, if I take $I=[m-m^{3/4},m+m^{3/4}]$, then I'd like to have some bound saying that $\mathbb P(\tau_B\in I)$ is small.

Dire of the dimension, not much can be said, in general.
So one would probably have to rely on the general tools such as martingale inequalities (e.g. Azuma) or the usual concentration of measure quantifiers such as the central limit theorem or more precisely the local central limit theorem.

Yes, it looks great! Thank you!

By obvious rescaling, without loss of generality $\sigma=1$. Assume also that $c_3:=E|X_1|^3<\infty$.
By the well-known result about the rate of convergence in boundary value problems for random walks, for $A:=(-\infty,-K\sqrt m]\cup(K\sqrt m,\infty)$,
$$|P(\tau_A\le m)-P(\max_{t\in[0,m]}|W_t|\ge K\sqrt m)|\le Cc_3/\sqrt m,$$
where $C$ is a universal positive real constant and $W_\cdot$ is a standard Wiener process. In turn, for real $K>0$,
$$P(\max_{t\in[0,m]}|W_t|\ge K\sqrt m)=P(\max_{t\in[0,1]}|W_t|\ge K)
\le2P(\max_{t\in[0,1]}W_t\ge K)=4P(W_1\ge K)
\le2e^{-K^2/2},$$
which is small for large $K$; the second equality in the above display holds by the reflection principle. So,
$$P(\tau_A\le m)\le2e^{-K^2/2}+Cc_3/\sqrt m,$$
which is small for large $K$ and large $m$.

Similarly, for $B:=[3\sqrt m,\infty)$,
$$|P(\tau_B\in[m-m^{3/4},m+m^{3/4}])-P(M_{m-m^{3/4}}<3\sqrt m\le 
M_{m+m^{3/4}})|\le Cc_3/\sqrt m,$$
where $M_t:=\max_{s\in[0,t]} W_s$. In turn,
$$
\begin{aligned}
&P(M_{m-m^{3/4}}<3\sqrt m\le M_{m+m^{3/4}}) \\ 
&=P(M_{1-m^{-1/4}}<3\le M_{1+m^{-1/4}}) \\
&=P(M_{1+m^{-1/4}}\ge3)-P(M_{1-m^{-1/4}}\ge3) \\ 
&=2P(W_{1+m^{-1/4}}\ge3)-2P(W_{1-m^{-1/4}}\ge3) \\ 
&=2P\Big(W_1\ge\frac3{\sqrt{1+m^{-1/4}}}\Big)
-2P\Big(W_1\ge\frac3{\sqrt{1-m^{-1/4}}}\Big) \\ 
&\le2\times3\Big(\frac1{\sqrt{1-m^{-1/4}}}-\frac1{\sqrt{1+m^{-1/4}}}\Big)f\Big(\frac3{\sqrt{1+m^{-1/4}}}\Big) \\ 
&\le\frac{6m^{-1/4}}{(1-m^{-1/4})^{3/2}}f\Big(\frac3{\sqrt{1+m^{-1/4}}}\Big), 
\end{aligned}$$
where $f$ is the standard normal p.d.f.
So,
$$P(\tau_B\in[m-m^{3/4},m+m^{3/4}])
\le\frac{6m^{-1/4}}{(1-m^{-1/4})^3}f\Big(\frac3{\sqrt{1+m^{-1/4}}}\Big) +Cc_3/\sqrt m,$$
which is small for large $m$.

If only the first two moments of $X_1$ are known to be finite, then no rate of convergence obtains -- cf. e.g. the Berry--Esseen bound.
